# Not as expected margin in CSS Media Query

Tags: html, css, media-queries

In this template I got bad margin I tried to change margin top and down but still do not show as expected.

http://jsbin.com/ijuwUpOB/11/edit

Can anyone figure out what the problem?

Comment: What does not show as expected? The jsbin looks ok. Please be more specific or add an image, so we can see what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you mean the wrong height on hovering a list item, right?
You set a fixed height of 30 there, which is too small for the list items.
Change this height to auto:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) and (min-width: 150px) {
  nav li:hover ul {
    height: auto;
  }
}
```